# Setting value in nsuserdefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm new to Objective-C and XCode and I've encountered such a problem.

How do you properly save the value to `NSUserDefaults`.

I have value in

```
[_textFields objectAtIndex:2]).text
```

And trying to do this

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:((UITextField *)[_textFields objectAtIndex:2]).text))  forKey:@"Phone"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

How do you do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setObject:forKey:` instead of `setValue:forKey:`

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:((UITextField *)[_textFields objectAtIndex:2]).text)) forKey:@"Phone"];
```

Update:
You code will work if you really have that text field in the array. Here is the step by step broken down code to make it more clear:

```
UITextField* textField = [_textFields objectAtIndex:2]; // get your text field
NSString* text = textField.text; // get the actual value we are going to store
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:text forKey:@"Phone"]; // store it
```

Comment: I'v also wanted to know how to do it properly (in syntax) because my described set value is sintaxly wrong:)

Comment: Heh, that's just exactly like i did just now. I guess it will do for now. Thank you for time helping.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with strings values. You should use setObjectForKey (save) and objectForKey (read). Here's an example

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *yourText = [[_textFields objectAtIndex:2] text]; // Your text

// Save
[userDefaults setObject:yourText forKey:kKey];
[userDefaults synchronize];

// Read
NSString *result = (NSString *) [userDefaults objectForKey:kKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method `setObject:forKey:` instead of `setValue:forKey:`

In `NSUserDefaults` class:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:"Your Object" forKey:@"Phone"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `setObject:forKey:` if you want to store property list objects (dictionaries, arrays, strings and numbers) in `NSUserDefaults`. [See the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)